# How to display customer email in orders.csv

Tags: magento

can someone help me? how can I add a new field in orders.csv file in Mangento? for example i want to have in csv file email and phone.

please click the link below to understand which export is talking about
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBAHG.png

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to customize the Grid block : /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

So You can do like this. If you already enabled the local module functionality, Please copy and paste it to this path /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

And Open that new file ( pasted ), check this method _prepareColumns().
In this method, you have to add those attributes which you are gonna to export in order.csv.
Check the following:

```
....
    $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Email'),
        'index' => 'customer_email',
    ));        
....
```

After this, refresh the magento cache.

Please check the following code:
In Grid.php

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
      $collection->getSelect()
        ->join(
           'customer_entity',
           'main_table.customer_id = customer_entity.entity_id', array('customer_email' => 'email')
    );
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Then in protected function _prepareColumns() function add following code:

```
$this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Email'),
        'index' => 'customer_email',
    ));
```

After this, you must refresh the cache or login again.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer but this field appear only in grid, not in CSV file, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Please check my answer again. I have just updated it.

Comment: yes thank you so much is perfect :) you save my life, can you tell me how can I add phone number?

Comment: I check right now again your code, and i see some orders is missing do you have any idea?